# Best / easiest strings to find / replace

Tags: c#, replace

I need to replace a few placeholders in articles, such as images for example.

I was considering the format of `:imageX:` where X is the GUID of the image.

But is there a better string to use, as I have to search for `:image`, then take the GUID until the ending `:`.

**Is there a better/easier string to do for this kind of replacement?**

There will be multiple `:imageX:` placeholders throughout the article, and there will be additional placeholders such as `:videoX:` and so on.

I will of course, replace in the article `:imageX:` with the `<img` tag with the url to the correct image and other tags for other placeholders.

--

The ask widget already claims that the question is subjective and likely to be closed, so please if this is not the right place to ask this, suggest a better one. I feel it should be fine as it is about code and there can be a definitive easiest (shortest/simplest) code for replacing these, given that we find here the best placeholder string to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a good enough string to use for that. As there is a GUID in there, it's extremely unlikely that someone would write that and not intend for it to be replaced.

You can use a regular expression to catch all such placeholders and replace them. It will help you extract the identifier and the guid, and you can create the replacement code from that.

Example:

```
article = Regex.Replace(article, @":(\w+)(\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}):", m => {
  string content = m.Groups[1].Value;
  string guid = m.Groups[2].Value;
  switch (content) {
    case "image": return "<img src=\"getimage?guid=" + guid + "\" alt=\"image\">";
    case "video": return "<eeh... whatevs>";
  }
  return m.Value; // unrecognised content, so leave it unchanged
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is best solution for this, you can choose whatever format of the characters to replace with, just make you are not using something that may be like a normal text, for example: is there a chance that your text contain :imageX: and you don't want to replace?
Then write your code and test, refine.

Comment: >> is there a chance that your text contain :imageX: and you don't want to replace? << no.

Comment: >> Then write your code and test, refine. << yeah, trying to avoid that :P thinking that someone must have dealt with this before.

Comment: yes, we all dealt with, and I don't think someone will tell you a best solution.

Comment: well, in that case, your answer will be the accepted one ;)